# Have a issue when using preg_replace function

Tags: php, preg-replace

There is a issue when I use this native php function: preg_replace.
Does any one experience this case? 
When I run this simple script:

```
echo preg_replace('/amount_number/i','$100',"this is amount: amount_number");
```

It only output:

```
this is amount: 0
```

Tried another case:

```
echo preg_replace('/amount_number/i','$11100',"this is amount: amount_number");
```

Output:

```
this is amount: 100
```

Seems the output string was cut "$" sign and next 2 letters.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `$10` is used get the capture group(*tenth*) from the regex. So, you have to escape that with `\`, like this([DEMO](https://eval.in/930791)):

```
echo preg_replace('/amount_number/i','\$100',"this is amount: amount_number");
```

Output:

```
this is amount: $100
```